# Do apps still get access to Tokens if the user turns of location services?

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, token, access-token

Do apps (iOS & Android) still get access to Tokens if the user turns of location services?

Our app has a log-in api. It needs basic info such as username, password and token. If the token is Null, the user will not be able to log in. Would this be an issue if the user turns off location services? Does turning location service off mean no token for device?

Comment: What does this even mean in the context of iOS? Is the token a string, and if so, why would location services have anything to do with it? If it's not a string, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does turning location service off mean no token for device?

No  `location` has nothing to do with the `push notification`.

They are seperate features, that require different permissions.

Comment: Oh, I think I should've phrased the question as: 
Can the user turn off any options to disable the token option?

Comment: if the user does not give permission to the push notification then you wont get the token...